# How to get elasped time of a video in flash and php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, flash

Here is the situation :

When a user watches the full duration of a video,  I would like to add a new row to the database. For example, if there is a video of 100 MB with a duration of 2 hours and the user watches the full video add a new row, else do nothing.

I am using [JW player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/) and js.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, i don't know about jw player precisely, but i guess your flash triggers an event when the video reaches the end. On that event you can link a call to a php page that add something into your db to specify the movie was seen til the end.

But, nothing says the users hasn't moved forward and skipped half of the video, then you would need to mesure time. But again, nothing says that the user hasn't paused, or get back some minutes ago in the video :)